# Value of type 'Double' has no member 'roundDouble'

Tags: swift

I am trying to code a weather app in swift and I keep getting this

> error: Value of type 'Double' has no member 'roundDouble'.

This is the line resulting in the error

```
WeatherRow(logo: "thermometer", name: "Max temp", value: (weather.main.tempMax.roundDouble() + "°"))

struct MainResponse: Decodable {
    var temp: Double
    var feels_like: Double
    var temp_min: Double
    var temp_max: Double
    var pressure: Double
    var humidity: Double
}
```

Comment: Why do you think a `roundDouble` method exists? Where do you expect it to come from?

Comment: `tempMax.rounded()`. However, you should probably use `MeasurementFormatter` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax to round is `round(var)`, not `var.roundDouble()`. ([example](https://www.advancedswift.com/rounding-floats-and-doubles-in-swift/))

Using the following function call: `round(weather.main.tempMax)`

Comment: There is also `Double.rounded()`

Comment: Not that the name of the property in the struct is `temp_max`, not `tempMax`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of converting a `Double` to `String`, use a *formatter*. In this case you can save yourself some work by using `MeasurementFormatter`, example:

```
let formatter = MeasurementFormatter()
formatter.numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0

let maxTemperature = 42.54
let measurement = Measurement(
    value: maxTemperature,
    unit: UnitTemperature.celsius
)

let formattedTemperature = formatter.string(from: measurement)
print(formattedTemperature) // 43°C
```

Answer (score 0):

In most cases you should not round floats/doubles, they are only approximations of real number, for example a double can not exactly store 1/10 for the same reason you can not store 1/3 with a finite number of decimal points, you are going to get gaps, and just have a less accurate value. The main reason to round is for display purposes, and so you should round when turning your value into a string to display, NumberFormatter has lots of control over this, you can also us c like print formatting options like "%.3f"